# Split data from select query and commit into temp table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a scenario where I'm creating a temp table with the data coming in from a select statement. My problem is when the data coming in from the select query is huge, I'm running into insufficient memory problems which results in my query failing to give results.

I was wondering if there was a way to commit a chunk of data (say every 1000 rows) into the temp table before moving on to the next one.

```
Eg:
CREATE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
   SELECT [ column1, column2...columnN ]
   FROM EXISTING_TABLE
   [ WHERE ] <ALL CONDITIONS>
```

Now lets assume that the inner select returns 100 rows. I don't want all the 100 rows to be inserted into the NEW_TABLE at once. I want to split this up. How do I go about efficiently doing this?

Comment: what is the exact error you get when running your CTAS against a large set of data?

Comment: @tbone unfortunately, I don't have the logs for the error. I was told that there was a memory error and that is what I'm going with.
I have been tasked with optimizing the existing query :(

Answer (score 0):

If you create temp table why you not create table as **GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE**, like this? :

```
CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
SELECT [ column1, column2...columnN ]
FROM EXISTING_TABLE
[ WHERE ] <ALL CONDITIONS>
ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS;
```

It can cause lower memory usage because of " **Decreased redo generation as, by definition, they are non-logging.**" (http://psoug.org/reference/gtt.html)

Elaborating on what I wrote:

"Redo records are buffered in a
circular fashion in the redo log
buffer of the SGA (see "How Oracle
Database Writes to the Redo Log" )
and are written to one of the redo
log files by the Log Writer (LGWR)
database background process." - docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/onlineredo001.htm

using global temporary let you avoiding redundant memory cost. I think you don't care about safety temporary data. Besides Global Temporary  Table default is written to temporary tablespace which is optimized for the storage of transient data.

" When Oracle needs to store data in a global temporary table or build a hash table for a hash join, Oracle also starts the operation in memory and completes the task without writing to disk if the amount of data involved is small enough. While populating a global temporary table or building a hash is not a sorting operation, we will lump all of these activities together in this paper because they are handled in a similar way by Oracle.

If an operation uses up a threshold amount of memory, then Oracle breaks the operation into smaller ones that can each be performed in memory. Partial results are written to disk in a temporary tablespace."

Basing on upon:
  - you use other memory area than default process memory (sga, undo) which appeared to small in your case
  -  when memory size will be insufficient -> oracle will write data to disk

Comment: Sorry I don't quite follow. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I think I have a temp solution/work around for my problem: Something like this:

```
DECLARE
    counter  number (6) := 1;
    cursor c1 is
        <select query>

         type t__data is table of c1%rowtype index by inary_integer;
         t_data t__data;

begin

   open c1;
   loop
      fetch c1 bulk collect into t_data; 
      exit when t_data.count = 0;

      for idx in t_data.first .. t_data.last loop

        insert into TEMP_ONE1 (x,y)
            values (t_data(idx).x, t_data(idx).y);
            counter := counter + 1;

         if  counter = 10000
         then
          counter := 0;
          commit;
         end if;

      end loop;

   end loop;
   close c1;

end;
```

Do you think this is a good solution to the problem?
(I ran the query for a small sample of data and it does work)